# Is there limit to number of files that can be cached in html5 manifest?

Tags: html, offline-caching, cache-manifest, app-offline.htm, html5mode

I have lot of .PNG images numbering from 1 to 259 with a total size 250kb. I need these images to be available as thumbnails when the app is used in offline mode. So I created the manifest including all of these resources and then added the manifest to the homepage of the app using the html5 directive  but the app failed to run offline. 
Here is the manifest below;

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# version 10000
# This is a comment
CACHE:
offline.htm
tomcart.htm
bridgeOut.htm
explanation.htm

XT_files/image001.png
XT_files/image002.png
XT_files/image003.png
XT_files/image004.png
XT_files/image005.png
XT_files/image006.png
XT_files/image007.png
XT_files/image008.png
XT_files/image009.png
XT_files/image010.png
XT_files/image011.png
XT_files/image012.png
XT_files/image013.png
XT_files/image014.png
XT_files/image015.png
XT_files/image016.png
XT_files/image017.png
XT_files/image018.png
XT_files/image019.png
XT_files/image020.png
XT_files/image021.png
XT_files/image022.png
XT_files/image023.png
XT_files/image024.png
XT_files/image025.png
XT_files/image026.png
XT_files/image027.png
XT_files/image028.png
XT_files/image029.png
XT_files/image030.png
XT_files/image031.png
XT_files/image032.png
XT_files/image033.png
XT_files/image034.png
XT_files/image035.png
XT_files/image036.png
XT_files/image037.png
XT_files/image038.png
XT_files/image039.png
XT_files/image040.png
XT_files/image041.png
XT_files/image042.png
XT_files/image043.png
XT_files/image044.png
XT_files/image045.png
XT_files/image046.png
XT_files/image047.png
XT_files/image048.png
XT_files/image049.png
XT_files/image050.png
XT_files/image051.png
XT_files/image052.png
XT_files/image053.png
XT_files/image054.png
XT_files/image055.png
XT_files/image056.png
XT_files/image057.png
XT_files/image058.png
XT_files/image059.png
XT_files/image060.png
XT_files/image061.png
XT_files/image062.png
XT_files/image063.png
XT_files/image064.png
XT_files/image065.png
XT_files/image066.png
XT_files/image067.png
XT_files/image068.png
XT_files/image069.png
XT_files/image070.png
XT_files/image071.png
XT_files/image072.png
XT_files/image073.png
XT_files/image074.png
XT_files/image075.png
XT_files/image076.png
XT_files/image077.png
XT_files/image078.png
XT_files/image079.png
XT_files/image080.png
XT_files/image081.png
XT_files/image082.png
XT_files/image083.png
XT_files/image084.png
XT_files/image085.png
XT_files/image086.png
XT_files/image087.png
XT_files/image088.png
XT_files/image089.png
XT_files/image090.png
XT_files/image091.png
XT_files/image092.png
XT_files/image093.png
XT_files/image094.png
XT_files/image095.png
XT_files/image096.png
XT_files/image097.png
XT_files/image098.png
XT_files/image099.png
XT_files/image100.png
XT_files/image101.png
XT_files/image102.png
XT_files/image103.png
XT_files/image104.png
XT_files/image105.png
XT_files/image106.png
XT_files/image107.png
XT_files/image108.png
XT_files/image109.png
XT_files/image110.png
XT_files/image111.png
XT_files/image112.png
XT_files/image113.png
XT_files/image114.png
XT_files/image115.png
XT_files/image116.png
XT_files/image117.png
XT_files/image118.png
XT_files/image119.png
XT_files/image120.png
XT_files/image121.png
XT_files/image122.png
XT_files/image123.png
XT_files/image124.png
XT_files/image125.png
XT_files/image126.png
XT_files/image127.png
XT_files/image128.png
XT_files/image129.png
XT_files/image130.png
XT_files/image131.png
XT_files/image132.png
XT_files/image133.png
XT_files/image134.png
XT_files/image135.png
XT_files/image136.png
XT_files/image137.png
XT_files/image138.png
XT_files/image139.png
XT_files/image140.png
XT_files/image141.png
XT_files/image142.png
XT_files/image143.png
XT_files/image144.png
XT_files/image145.png
XT_files/image146.png
XT_files/image147.png
XT_files/image148.png
XT_files/image149.png
XT_files/image150.png
XT_files/image151.png
XT_files/image152.png
XT_files/image153.png
XT_files/image154.png
XT_files/image155.png
XT_files/image156.png
XT_files/image157.png
XT_files/image158.png
XT_files/image159.png
XT_files/image160.png
XT_files/image161.png
XT_files/image162.png
XT_files/image163.png
XT_files/image164.png
XT_files/image165.png
XT_files/image166.png
XT_files/image167.png
XT_files/image168.png
XT_files/image169.png
XT_files/image170.png
XT_files/image171.png
XT_files/image172.png
XT_files/image173.png
XT_files/image174.png
XT_files/image175.png
XT_files/image176.png
XT_files/image177.png
XT_files/image178.png
XT_files/image179.png
XT_files/image180.png
XT_files/image181.png
XT_files/image182.png
XT_files/image183.png
XT_files/image184.png
XT_files/image185.png
XT_files/image186.png
XT_files/image187.png
XT_files/image188.png
XT_files/image189.png
XT_files/image190.png
XT_files/image191.png
XT_files/image192.png
XT_files/image193.png
XT_files/image194.png
XT_files/image195.png
XT_files/image196.png
XT_files/image197.png
XT_files/image198.png
XT_files/image199.png
XT_files/image200.png
XT_files/image201.png
XT_files/image202.png
XT_files/image203.png
XT_files/image204.png
XT_files/image205.png
XT_files/image206.png
XT_files/image207.png
XT_files/image208.png
XT_files/image209.png
XT_files/image210.png
XT_files/image211.png
XT_files/image212.png
XT_files/image213.png
XT_files/image214.png
XT_files/image215.png
XT_files/image216.png
XT_files/image217.png
XT_files/image218.png
XT_files/image219.png
XT_files/image220.png
XT_files/image221.png
XT_files/image222.png
XT_files/image223.png
XT_files/image224.png
XT_files/image225.png
XT_files/image226.png
XT_files/image227.png
XT_files/image228.png
XT_files/image229.png
XT_files/image230.png
XT_files/image231.png
XT_files/image232.png
XT_files/image233.png
XT_files/image234.png
XT_files/image235.png
XT_files/image236.png
XT_files/image237.png
XT_files/image238.png
XT_files/image239.png
XT_files/image240.png
XT_files/image241.png
XT_files/image242.png
XT_files/image243.png
XT_files/image244.png
XT_files/image245.png
XT_files/image246.png
XT_files/image247.png
XT_files/image248.png
XT_files/image249.png
XT_files/image250.png
XT_files/image251.png
XT_files/image252.png
XT_files/image253.png
XT_files/image254.png
XT_files/image255.png
XT_files/image256.png
XT_files/image257.png
XT_files/image258.png
XT_files/image259.png
Images/infomas.png
Images/futminna-logo.png
CSS/css/light-modal.min
CSS/css/animate.css
CSS/css/bootstrap.css
CSS/css/bootstrap.min.css
CSS/css/styles.css
Js/js/jquery.min.js

NETWORK:
server/server.php

#Note:
#The total file size to be cached for this app is 850kb.
```

I have used manifest before but with limited number of files which works fine... I don't know why this is failing to work. Is there a way out of this? Any workable solution will be well appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you generate these images dynamically using canvas?

Answer (score 0):

Application cache manifest is deprecated and doesn't work in Chrome 83+

https://caniuse.com/#feat=offline-apps

https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6192449487634432

> New Web applications should be built around Service Workers. Existing
>   applications that use AppCache should migrate to Service Workers.